# Intellij running one test in TestNG

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

So my typical workflow is

1. I write a data driven test using TestNG in IntelliJ.
2. I supply hundreds of data items
3. Run the test and one or two of them fail
4. I see the list of passed/failed tests in the "Run" pane.

I would like the ability to just right click that "instance" of the test and run that test alone (with breakpoints). Currently IntelliJ does not seem to have that feature. I would have to right click the test and when I run, it runs the whole set of tests with hundreds of data points.

Is this possible?

Comment: +1 If this is not possible then I have another argument to add to my list of reasons to stick with eclipse :-).

Answer (score 2):

TestNG supports this at the `testng.xml` level, where you can specify which indices of your data provider should be used. It's called "invocation-numbers" and you can see what it looks like by running a test with a data provider, failing some of its invocation numbers and looking at the `testng-failed.xml` that gets generated.

Back to your question: your IDE needs to support this feature in order to make it available in the UI, so I suggest you ask on the IDEA forums

Comment: Thanks Cedric. I guessed it is not possible at least not in IntelliJ 11.x but just wanted to make sure I was not missing out on something. I currently use the testng-failed.xml to rerun failed tests which is the second best thing to the IDE supporting it.

Answer (score 0):

The feature has been added as of Intellij `142.1217`: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-57906