# Running TestNG Test in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

After running `Rebuild Project` successfully in `IntelliJ 13.1.3 Ultimate IDE`, I opened my Test NG test file.

When right-clicking on the file, I don't see any option to run the test.

How can I run an TestNG test in `IntelliJ 13.1.3`?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12932686/409976) is similar, but it's from 2012 with an unaccepted answer.

Comment: What *do* you see? Any run menu option at all?  When that happens for me sometimes waiting a minute fixes it... :| Also removing .iml and .IDEA folder sometimes fixes it

Answer (score 6):

## Yes you can!

Сheck the folder that contains the test classes whether marked as [`Test Source Root`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html). In another case see whether installed [TestNG-J](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/137?pr=idea) plugin.

## Update:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, for my module I verified that `src/test/java` was listed as a `Test Source Folder` per your link, but I get `0 test class found in package xyz` when trying to run the test from IntelliJ.

Comment: @KevinMeredith You can run all test class as is present in screenshot ? *See updates*.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 possibilities in the new Intellij 2017.2 to run a testNG test.

1. You can click on the module (project) name >>Run>>All Tests(TNG). Be careful as there are 2 'All Tests' options. The second option is the one you need. It carries a testNG logo. This way you can run all your testNG classes in parallel
2. The second possibility is to run a single TestNG class. Righ click the class name in the package explorer and choose 'Run Test' If your class is a testNG class, by default, the test will run as a TestNG test.
3. This option is my favourite as it gives me a lot of control over my tests. Install this 'Create TestNG XML' [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9556-create-testng-xml). Once installed. if you right click on your module name, you will see a new option called 'Create TESTNG XML' and you will be able to directly use that option to run your TestNG tests, giving you a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that a plugin that you need is disabled.

Make sure the testNg plugin is enabled.

I noticed this plugin wasn't enabled,
and as soon as I turned it on, everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

Besides possible reasons outlined in the rest of responses, there is also one other possible alternative scenario where tests are not "found".

Make sure that your test classes are of `public` scope. If they are package protected, they won't be found by IntelliJ plugin (but they will be executed via Maven).